# Get ordered Stream from LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, java-stream

How can I get an ordered `Stream` from a `LinkedHashMap<String,Object>`?

I can get a sorted `Stream` using `map.entrySet().stream().sorted()`, but that will sort the items by their natural ordering, and does not support insertion order from the `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: Well, remove the `.sorted()`.

Comment: so do u want sorted list or ordered list ?

Comment: if you want ordered list , then remove .sorted() as mentioned by @JBNizet

Answer (score 2):

It will occur naturally without any intervention.  Note that I chose very large keys to avoid the likelyhood of collisions which would taint the demo.

```
    Random r = new Random(37);
    List<Integer> originalOrder = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<Integer,Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        int key = r.nextInt(1000000);
        int value = r.nextInt(100);
        originalOrder.add(value);
        map.put(key,value);
    }
    System.out.println(originalOrder);
    System.out.println(map.values());
    map.values().stream().forEach(a->System.out.print(" " + a + " "));
    System.out.println();
    map.entrySet().stream().forEach(a->System.out.print(" " + a.getValue() + " "));
```

Should print this or something similar

> [23, 18, 26, 73, 0, 6, 91, 94, 31] 
>   [23, 18, 26, 73, 0, 6, 91, 94, 31] 
>    23  18  26  73  0  6  91  94  31  
>    23  18  26  73  0  6  91  94  31